# Can $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{z+k}-1}$ be expressed in a more compact form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'd like to have a more compact form for

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{z+k}-1}$$

Could anyone devise something?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203125/can-this-series-be-expressed-in-closed-form-and-if-so-what-is-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function can be represented in terms (and is actually quite close to the definition) of the [q-Polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). See equation (2).

Comment: Even better, see the "Lambert series" (7) on the same page.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not sure the Lambert series is enough to write the OP's function for every $z.$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica gives

$$f(z)=-\frac{\text{Log}[2]+2 \text{Log}\left[2^{-z}\right]+2 \text{QPolyGamma}\left[0,-\frac{\text{Log}\left[2^{-z}\right]}{\text{Log}[2]},2\right]}{\text{Log}[4]}$$